# Circumstance usage with grammar

Tags: meaning-in-context

Would it be better to say:  “If I was in your circumstance,
I hope, I truly hope, I’d do the right thing.” OR “If I were faced with your circumstance, I hope, I truly hope, I’d do the right thing.”

Comment: Using Simple Past *(was)* instead of Subjunctive *(were)* is a stylistic choice - they're both perfectly valid and mean the same. We usually pluralise *your **circumstances*** in such constructions, but that doesn't affect meaning either. Nor do I see any credible case for suggesting it makes any difference whether you hypothesise *being **in*** in those circumstances, or *being **faced with*** them.

Comment: Is this a question about the difference between using *circumstance* vs *circumstances* or about the difference betw *was* vs *were* ?